# batch: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that copies Unrar.exe. But when I run it, it says: The system cannot the file specified. But when I check the path, it is correct. Here's my code:

```
if exist %ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Unrar.exe copy /y %ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Unrar.exe %cd%\Unrar.exe >nul
```

Why is this saying The system cannot the file specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%ProgramFiles% refers to 'C:\Program Files' folder. On command line paths containing spaces must be enclosed between quotation marks. For ex.

%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Unrar.exe should be written as "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\Unrar.exe"

I also noticed %cd% variable, you better check if this variable refers to a valid path.

Comment: @Sekan BAYKAL Yes, %cd% is a variable, it refers to the current path. Try typing echo %cd% into cmd.exe.